# Add a static/hardcoded price if textfield contains text

Tags: php, price, jquery

I have a textbox that is shown on some products so that people can type a name or word that they want engraved onto the item they are buying. Now my issue is if they type something in the textbox and click add to cart I need a hardcoded price added ontop of the products base price. So say the item is $100.00 and they type a word in the textbox and click add to cart the item should then have its price changed to $106.99

My issue is I am not sure how to go about changing the products price if a textbox contains a value.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the Magento admin panel using Custom Options.

On the product to be modified, go to Custom Options and click Add New Option.

Choose Input Type: Text Field, set Required to No, and set your price as 6.99.

When saved this will give the product a text option which when filled will add 6.99 to the price. It is important to note that prices on custom options are always additional to the product price, unless you have any extensions in place that allow these to set the final price.

Note: it is also possible to reduce the price using a custom option, by prefixing the price with a minus sign '-'